# Не работает анимация ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Почему не работает анимация?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import style from "./productItem.module.css";
import ProductModal from "../productModal/productModal";
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from "react-addons-css-transition-group";
import { Card, Icon, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";

class ProductItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openModal: false
    };
  }

  getProductById = idProduct => {
    return this.props.productsList.find(product => product.id === idProduct);
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      openModal: !this.state.openModal
    });
  };

  render() {
    const productData = this.props.productData;

    return (
      <div>
                <div>
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="menu"
            transitionAppear={true}
            transitionAppearTimeout={700}
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeave={true}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={800}
          >
            {this.state.openModal && 
              <ProductModal
                productId={productData.id}
                isModalOpened={this.state.openModal}
                handleModal={this.openModal}
                productsList={this.props.productsList}
                getProductById={this.getProductById}
                key='1'
              />
            }
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
        <Card
          className={style.product_card}
          centered={true}
          color="red"
          raised
          data-product={productData.id}
          onClick={this.openModal}
        >
          <Image centered={true} src={productData.img} wrapped ui={false} />

          <Card.Content>
            <Icon
              circular={true}
              bordered={true}
              color="grey"
              size="big"
              className={style.zoom_icon}
              name="zoom-in"
            />
            <Card.Header>{productData.title}</Card.Header>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductItem;
```

Стили:

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Хочу сделать анимацию для открытия модального окна(ProductModal)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="menu" ...>
```

transitionName должен быть связан с вашими стилями по названию. 
Тут вы пишите `menu`, а в css `example`

Замените стили на

```
.menu-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.menu-enter.menu-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.menu-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-leave.menu-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

UPDATE
Проблема явно не в ReactCSSTransitionGroup,
вот скопировал ваши стили и сам ReactCSSTransitionGroup

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from "react-addons-css-transition-group";

const ProductItem = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(p => !p);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{isOpen ? "hide" : "show"}</button>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="menu"
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={700}
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeave={true}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={800}
      >
        {isOpen && (
          <p>
            ...
          </p>
        )}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </>
  );
};
export default ProductItem;
```

[image: Edit hopeful-germain-tr4m7]

Comment: Вы верно заметили, но, к сожалению, это не помогло(

Comment: Проблема именно в том, что вам нужно это сделать для модального окна, почитайте про ReactDOM.createPortal()